# Changing view center point changes location of subview while panning

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a view with an image and on `touchBegan` i scale the button down to 0.8 using `CGAffineTransform`

and in my `ViewController` i added a `panGesturdeRecognizer` for the view.

You can move the button only on the Y axis.

My problem is when changing the center point of the view while panning the subview image moves left.

[image: befor panning]  [image: after panning]
code:

```
class QTView: UIView {

lazy var image: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.image = UIImage(named: "image")
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return image
}()

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initialize()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initialize()
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)
        self.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    })

}


}

extension QTView {
fileprivate func initialize() {
    addSubview(image)

    backgroundColor = UIColor.white


    //border
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    layer.borderWidth = 3

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        image.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
        image.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
        image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
        image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
        ])

}
}
```

ViewController:

```
func OnPanListener(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.customView)

    guard let view = recognizer.view else {
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        return
    }

    //*0.8 because of scale animation
    let newY = view.center.y + (translation.y*0.8)
    view.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: newY)
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
}
```

Any suggestions whey is this happening?
Thanks